# bash- command not fount error

Tags: mac, terminal, bash, command-line, path

I tried to install omnet++ on my Macbook pro (OS 10.10) yesterday. I got an error so I delete path in my bash-profile.

Now, every command I try to run in my terminal shows an error of command not found. I try many ways but did not find a answer.

[image]

Comment: What explicitly and specifically do you mean by _"I got an error so I delete path in my bash-profile"_?  Also from `man path_helper`: "The path_helper utility should not be invoked directly.  It is intended only for use by the shell profile."

Comment: reset terminal back to the root directory.

Comment: this might help http://superuser.com/a/498356

Comment: You've basically deleted the path, which means the shell cannot find commands in `/usr/bin` and other such locations (those are the locations that contain commands like `tar`, `touch`, and everything). @Buscar웃 's pointing to something that will indeed help. Add the path back into the `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`, restart the shell, and that should be it.

Answer (score 1):

First, get your PATH back *for the current shell* by running

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
export PATH
```

Then fix the PATH problems

- edit your bash-profile and put back the line you've deleted. If you don't remember, take the two lines from above
- `path_helper` takes its input from the files in `/etc/paths.d`, at least one of those files seems to be corrupt (the last two entries in the output look kind of strange). To fix, run `/bin/ls -l /etc/paths.d` to get the name of the file containing the additions for omnet++ (should be named accordingly) and remove it with `sudo /bin/rm /etc/paths.d/NAME-OF-FILE`